# Configure a view to display nodes that match a term value of the container node

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have two content types:

- Programs
- Events

I have a vocabulary:

- Programs

I have a view that displays Events, and I place the view in my Programs nodes.

Both Programs and Events have a field_term_programs that references the Programs vocabulary. If I place the view in a Programs node, I want it to display any Events assigned to the same Programs term as that Programs node.  I have tried to set this up using contextual filters but have had no luck thus far.  The views block is displayed in the Programs node, but no nodes are displayed within the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to show sibling nodes through Taxonomy is one of the most common Views requests.

You case seems to be the simplest one, you can use the `Has taxonomy term ID` Contextual filter.

1. Create your Views listing Events
2. Add the `Has taxonomy term ID` Contextual filter and configure it:

   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   **Taxonomy term ID from URL**
   **Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks**
   **Filter to items that share any term**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
   **Specify validation criteria**
   **Taxonomy term ID**
   **[your vocabulary]**
   **Single ID**
3. Place your Block Display on Programs nodes and configure Block settings for the contextual filter.

Comment: It's not working yet.  I don't know why we would choose "Taxonomy term ID from URL" when there is no taxonomy term ID in the URL, but I did so anyway.  Also, I'm not sure what "configure block settings for the contextual filter" means.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: The wording can be a bit confusing, Views is a very complex and featurefull module. That option isn't referring to getting the info from the actual URL text, but from the node context. The following option illustrates that, you've chosen to pull information into your Views about the node that is currently being viewed, the info about the Taxonomy terms. After creating a Block display in your Views, you have to place the Block in a region in your theme so it can be displayed somewhere on your site. In those settings you'll see where you have to select again sth like "taxonomy term from url".

Comment: "you have to place the Block in a region in your theme so it can be displayed somewhere on your site".  The block is already displayed.  There are just no nodes being displayed within the block.  I see the block title.  And if I select "Display contents of 'No results found'" instead of "Provide default value," I can see the "No results" message.  I edited my question to clarify that the block is being displayed.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your Contextual filter configuration, and your Block configuration to your Question.

Comment: It's working now.  Your instructions are correct, but didn't work initially.  It seemed to start working when I removed the contextual filter altogether, and then removed a filter criteria, forcing some nodes to display.  I then added the filter criteria back, then added the contextual filter, and then it worked.  It's as if some cache had to be cleared that would not clear unless some filters were removed and then re-created.

Comment: I'm glad it's working :)